# Binary division algorithm in MIPS assembly language...help for one line?

Tags: assembly, binary, mips, division

Im having trouble with the following:

"Shift Remainder register left
setting rightmost bit to 0"

My attempt:
lui $s0, 1      # Shift Remainder register left by 1 bit

or should it be 1*4 = 4 instead of 1 for offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an instruction set reference? `lui` is Load Upper Immediate, it doesn't shift the register, it shifts the immediate, and by 16 bits. So `lui $s0, 1` just loads `0x00010000` into `$s0`.

To shift left, you can use the `sll` instruction, such as `sll $s0, $s0, 1`

Answer (score 0):

.data

prompt_devident:    .asciiz   "\n Enter your Devident :\n "
prompt_devider:     .asciiz   "Enter your Devider  :\n "
print_quotient: .asciiz   "Your quotient is :  "
print_reminder: .asciiz   "\n Your Reminder is:  "

.text
.globl main
main:

l4: la $a0, prompt_devident
    li $v0,4
    syscall

```
li $v0,5        
syscall        
move $t0,$v0        

la $a0, prompt_devider        
li $v0,4        
syscall        

li $v0,5        
syscall        
move $t1, $v0        

ori $t2,  $zero,0        
ori $t3,  $zero,0        
ori $t4,  $zero,0        
ori $t5,  $zero,32
```

loop:   sll $t2,$t2,1
    bgez $t0,l1
    ori $t2,$t2,1

l1:     sll $t0,$t0,1
    subu $t3,$t2,$t1
    bgez $t3,l2

l3:     addi $t4,$t4,1
    beq  $t4,$t5,next
    j loop

l2:     move $t2,$t3
    ori $t0,1
    j l3

next:   la $a0, print_quotient
    li $v0,4
    syscall

```
    move  $a0,$t0               
    li    $v0,1            
syscall            

la $a0, print_reminder            
li $v0,4            
syscall            

    move  $a0,$t2               
    li    $v0,1            
syscall            
j l4            

li $v0, 10            
syscall
```

Comment: Hello ! Could you explain a little bit ?